How to display a text message on a splash screen with pyi_splash.update_text("message")?
I am trying to show a text message on a splash screen using the command pyi_splash.update_text('message')
The example code here shows how to use pyinstaller to get the splash screen image to display and then to close later on Adding splash.
That example and the pyi_splash documentation mentions the .update_text() command documentation
But I do not see any text on my splash screen.
I have confirmed pyi_spalsh.isalive() is True before calling update_text but still no success
I am running on a Windows system. Does it only work on Linux perhaps?
Any suggestions?
Copying the example linked above, I run pyinstaller --splash myimage.png to build the executable.
I have this code at the top of my main function:
if '_PYIBoot_SPLASH' in os.environ and importlib.util.find_spec("pyi_splash"):
    import pyi_splash
    if (pyi_splash.is_alive()):
        print('Splash found alive')
    else:
        print('splash not found')
    pyi_splash.update_text('UI Loaded ...')

And the command prompt shows Splash found alive but update_text does not make any text appear.
The main function then goes on to do other stuff before calling pyi_splash.close() which does correctly close the splash screen
Do I need to set some other parameters to set the text size/position/color/opacity so that it is visible in the splash screen

did you run in console to see if it has some error messages? Did you use print() to see if this function was executed? Maybe you have it in wrong place or it needs something more. But you didn't show code so we can't help you

Thanks @furas I edited my question to show more of what I am doing.

I don't know how works code in splash but in some GUIs code doesn't update widgets directly but it waits for end of user's code to update all widgets at the same time (it makes less work to redraw window) but if code never ends then it can't update it - and GUIs may have special function which force to redraw window. For example tkinter uses root.update() (but this needs access to root). Maybe this is the problem.

@furas a good suggestion but the documentation for pyi_splash just shows the functions is_alive, update_text and close

The answer is the text display is turned off by default as explained in Using Spec Files in particular see the section The Splash Target
You have to manually edit the .spec file that pyinstaller generates when it is first run.
Replace text_pos=None, with a coordinate position like text_pos=(10,50),
Then run pysintaller yourFile.spec to build the exe from the spec file
